# Use multiple conditions with non-sequential string values to generate a new vector

Tags: r

Say, I have a numeric vector (v1) with the values 1:50 and another (v2) with values 1:4. 
I'd like to create a third vector (v3) that produces either "1" or "0" based on the 2 conditions from the values from the aforementioned vectors (v1, v2).

My approach is to first create a new vector of "0" values, then to implement the conditions as an indices, computing "1" where the conditions are met.

Here's what I have so far:

```
df$v3 <- "0" # first add new vector with values zero

score <-  (df$v1 %in% c(2,4:7,9,12:13,16,18:23,26,33,35,39,41:43,45:46) & 
df$v2 %in% c(1,2)) |    # first condition of the rule     

(df$v1 %in% c(1,3,8,10:11,14:15,17,24:25,27:32,34,36:38,40,44,47:50) & df$v2 
%in% c(3,4)) # second condition of the rule

df$v3[score] <- "1"  # coerce rule to add "1" value to v3

df$v3 <- factor(df$v3) # finish by converting to factor
```

The above code produces

```
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, AQ_mark, value = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  :
invalid factor level, NA generated"
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Try `df$v3 <- factor(0, levels=0:1)` to create the new factor so when you go to add 1 into the list, it's already known to be a level. It seems that `v3` already exists as a factor with levels.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you want v3 to be a factor? v3 is a factor with a single level because default R settings are to treat string columns as factors, and you intially set every row to the string "0".

I'd suggest assigning v3 using your condition:

```r
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(v1 = sample(1:50, 10, TRUE), v2 = sample(1:4, 10, TRUE))

cond1 <- df$v1 %in% c(2,4:7,9,12:13,16,18:23,26,33,35,39,41:43,45:46) & 
    df$v2 %in% c(1,2) # first condition of the rule     
cond2 <- df$v1 %in% c(1,3,8,10:11,14:15,17,24:25,27:32,34,36:38,40,44,47:50) & 
    df$v2 %in% c(3,4) # second condition of the rule

df$v3 <-  cond1 | cond2 

#if you really want a factor

df$v3 <- as.factor(cond1 | cond2)
```